# keeping a browse button stick to last option of QCompleter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

is it possible to have a Browse button in just the text that stays in the last option of `QCompleter` in a way that even if user is scrolling up or down a huge list the browse button/option says there. Cosider the `setMaxVisible` is set to 4 and the list is a huge as 10 or 20, scrolling the suggestions the browse button stays there in the `QCompleter` popup.

[image]